# How to take form information entered into an info array, and print out that array to a paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, concatenation, paragraph

I am trying to take form information, enter them into an info array and then print out that array to a paragraph within a string concatenation.

Here's my HTML:

```
<body>
   <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter first name">
   <input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Enter last name">
   <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter age">
   <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
   <button>Add Info</button>
   <article>
      <div>
         <p>8</p>
      </div>
   </article>
   <p id="future"></p>
   <main>
</body>
```

Here's my Javascript:

```
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const paras = document.querySelectorAll('p');

    btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
      const name = document.getElementById("#name");
      const lName = document.querySelector("#lname");
      const age = document.querySelector("#age");
      const email = document.querySelector("#email");
      let info = [name + " " + lName + " , you are " + age + "!" + " But by your next birthday, you will 
      inherit $10 million dollars! We will email you your fortune to: " + email + "."];
      document.querySelector("#future").innerHTML = info;})
```

I get:

> null [object HTMLInputElement] , you are [object HTMLInputElement]! But by your next     birthday, you will inherit $10 million dollars! We will email you your fortune to: null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. `getElementById` expects only the id as argument, without `#`. (`querySelector` need this, because it takes a css-selector as argument).
2. There's a typo in this selector: `const lName = document.querySelector("#lname")`: `#lName` instead of `#lname`.
3. You printed the input-elements, not their values. Use `.value` for that.

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
const paras = document.querySelectorAll('p');

btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
  const name = document.getElementById("name");
  const lName = document.querySelector("#lName");
  const age = document.querySelector("#age");
  const email = document.querySelector("#email");
  let info = [name.value + " " + lName.value + " , you are " + age.value + "!" + " But by your next birthday, you will inherit $10 million dollars!We will email you your fortune to: " + email.value + "."];
  document.querySelector("#future").innerHTML = info;
})
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="text" id="name" placeholder="Enter first name">
  <input type="text" id="lName" placeholder="Enter last name">
  <input type="text" id="age" placeholder="Enter age">
  <input type="text" id="email" placeholder="Enter email address">
  <button>Add Info</button>

  <article>
    <div>
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <p id="future"></p>

</body>
```

Comment: Are you helping someone to scam people?